# How to speed up multiple facebook likebox loading time at one time

Tags: javascript, facebook

My question as titled. I have a webpage to display all of students' project overview, each one have a likebox. Total number is around 36, it means this page needed to load around 36 facebook social plugin: likebox at one time.

Then, I follow all steps on a facebook offcial blog article: "How-To: Optimize Social Plugin Performance" http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/. It seems to be better now. 
But it still takes around 10 secs to load contents of all plugins by waiting 'www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php'.

Does anyone have any ideas about speeding up multiple facebook plugins which takes lower than 5 secs in the meantime??

Thanks for your helps in advance.